# read all files in a directory php

Tags: php, cakephp

Good day every one

I have a problem.
I have a folder in my webroot/files that has some documents in it, mainly doc files.
I want to read all the contents of the files. e.g. if there are 2 files, namely users.docx and funds.docx.
I want to be able to open each file, read its content, and write them to a single document.

so far the code i have writes only the 1st file, but the newly written file has a size of both the read files.

```
function writeToFile($insId,$path,$hospital){
         $data = '';
        $my_file  =  WWW_ROOT . 'files' . DS . 'instructions' . DS . $insId . DS ."Final Report ".$insId.".rtf";

                            $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w')or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file); //implicitly creates file
                            foreach($hospital as $h){
                            $data .= file_get_contents($path.'/'.$h, false);
                            $data .= "\n";
                            echo($h."\n");
                            }
                            file_put_contents($my_file, $data);
                           fclose($handle);
     }
```

Comment: Do you think concatenating two Word documents' contents is going to give you a valid file?

Comment: I don't know the docx format but I would assume it's binary or at the very least some kind of XML structure. You're going to have to do a ton more work than a simple read/write for this one I'm afraid.

Comment: Have a look at http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.dir.php

Comment: docx is zip compressed xml files http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205.aspx . You can't just concatenate the raw binary together and expect it to work.

Answer (score 0):

A docx file is actually a directory so you will need to open that if you want to actually get to the xml that makes up the file. However, the contents of the directory is pretty complex and consists of many different files.

It's very unlikely that you will be able to find the right parts of each file and combine them together to make a valid file afterwards with a script.